# images doesn't save as array in database laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I want to save images in db like:

```
{
    "1":"accounts\/29cc60f2-c018-403c-80a9-94cda509e0f7.jpeg",
    "2":"accounts\/c2658592-526a-426e-9834-084e0252c4c5.jpeg",
    "3":"accounts\/3db1d928-e32f-4f3e-b41e-c99ffefec952.jpeg",
    "4":"accounts\/4d421a36-dc7e-4252-b806-17467a515aa7.jpeg"
}
```

but in response just recieve one data in output in db like :
["property/March2023/535856080.png"]

in my code :
in model :

```
    protected $fillable
        = [
            'images',
        ];
    protected $casts
        = [
            'images' => 'array',
        ];
```

in controller :

```
        $image_exists = $request->file('images');

        if ($image_exists !== Null) {
                    $images = array();
            $date = now()->format('F') . now()->format('Y');
            if ($files = $request->file('images')) {
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $name = rand() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $file->store('image', 'public');
                    $images[] = 'property/' . $date . '/' . $name;
                }
            }
            dd($images);
            $property = DB::table('re_properties')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();

            DB::table('re_properties')->where('id', $property->id)->update([

                'images' => $images,
            ]);
        } else {

        }
```

Comment: are you passing an array of files? can you dump the file array?

Answer (score 0):

you must first use **implode()** to save the images and save like in

```
"property/March2023/2061010485.png,property/March2023/1949282764.png,property/March2023/1065750317.png"
```

Try this:

```
DB::table('re_properties')->where('id', $property->id)->update([
        'images' => implode(",", $images),
    ]);
```

and for get images use **explode()** and get data like in

```
[
  "property/March2023/2061010485.png",
  "property/March2023/1949282764.png",
  "property/March2023/1065750317.png"
]
```

Try this:

```
$images = explode(",", DB::table('re_properties')->where('id', $property->id)->first()->images);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you save data, you can use **serialize()** to convert array to string & also use **base64_encode()** to encode data.

```
$data = [
    "accounts/29cc60f2-c018-403c-80a9-94cda509e0f7.jpeg",
    "accounts/c2658592-526a-426e-9834-084e0252c4c5.jpeg",
    "accounts/3db1d928-e32f-4f3e-b41e-c99ffefec952.jpeg",
    "accounts/4d421a36-dc7e-4252-b806-17467a515aa7.jpeg"
];

$images = base64_encode(serialize($data));
Re_properties::create([
  'images' => $images,
]);


/**
 * FOR CORE PHP
 * ____________
 * $string = base64_encode(serialize($data));
 * $sql = "INSERT INTO tb1 (col1) VALUES ('".$string."')";
*/
```

When you fetch data, you can us **unserialize()** & **base64_decode()** to decode data & convert string to array.

```
$re_property = Re_properties::find(1);
$images = unserialize(base64_decode($re_property->images));
echo $images[0]; // output : accounts/29cc60f2-c018-403c-80a9-94cda509e0f7.jpeg


/**
 * FOR CORE PHP
 * ____________
 * $sql = "SELECT col1 FROM tb1 WHERE id=1";
 * $result = $conn->query($sql);

 * if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 *   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 *     $data = unserialize(base64_decode($row['col1']));
 *     print_r($data);
 *   }
 * }
 * /
```